# Add PowerShell Core to Visual Studio's list of terminals

Tags: visual-studio, powershell-core

In Visual Studio, when I press `Ctrl-Backtick`, Visual Studio opens a "Developer PowerShell" window. How do I add PowerShell Core to the list of available terminals and make PowerShell Core the default?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2019, PowerShell Core 7...

1. Click on the **Settings** (gear) icon.
2. Click the **Add** button to add a new profile.
3. Set the **Name** to `PowerShell Core`.
4. Set the **Shell location** to `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe`
5. Clear the **Arguments**.
6. Press the **Apply** button.
7. Press the **Set as Default** button.

[image]